# What's the best oneliner to validate 2 date containing strings?

Tags: php

I thought in this one liner, but I guess there could be better or shorter approaches.

```
try { new \DateTime($dti); new \DateTime($dtf); $dtok = true;} catch(Exception $e) { $dtok = false; };
```

I mean a validation that only checks it's a valid date. Anyone has a better one ?

Comment: What type of date validation do you mean?

Comment: Good point. Edited the question.